# Does lock.notify() gets executed only at the end of the loop in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, wait, notify

```
public class MyVisibility {

    private static int count = 0;
    private static Object lock = new Object();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyVisibility.thread1().start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
        new MyVisibility.thread2().start();
    }


    static class thread1 extends Thread {

        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            while (true) {

                synchronized (lock) {

                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Thread one count is  " + count);
                    try {
                        lock.wait();

                        System.out.println("i am notified");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (count > 5) {

                    return;
                }

            }


        }
    }


    static class thread2 extends Thread {

        int i = 10;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            while (true) {

                synchronized (lock) {


                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Thead 2 count  is " + count);

                    lock.notify();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


                if (count > 10) {
                    return;

                }

            }


        }
    }


}
```

In above code, 
Current result on execution : I can see lock.notify() is getting called only after end of the while loop.

My assumption is Since lock.notify() is getting called immediately after count variable getting incremented, and immediately it should notify the waiting thread to resume its execution, instead after second thread completion of execution call is going for waiting thread to resume, what is the reason for this, can someone correct me what was wrong with my understanding.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you expected and the actual output.

Comment: Hint: calling `sleep(...)` inside a `synchronized` block or a `synchronized` method is practically always a Bad Idea.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yeah I am aware of it,If you see on first thread I haven't used sleep I was experimenting something and didn't remove that code in second thread while positing here..

Answer (score 0):

Your deduction - *"I can see lock.notify() is getting called only after end of the while loop"* is not entirely correct. Try running multiple times, or put break point just after `synchronized` block of thread2, and then you will see thread1 *"i am notified"* being printed.

From documentation of `notify()` -

> The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current
>   thread relinquishes the lock on this object

In your case before thread2 relinquishes lock and then thread1 acquires lock, thread2 acquires lock again by going into `synchronized` block.

Comment: May be , Call to notify indeed notifies the waiting thread immediately, but we can't know when it'll resume its execution. That's up to operating system's scheduler to decide. For instance, if your hardware supports only one active thread at any instance, Thread1 won't be able to run until Thread2 completes its execution, Will this also be could be a reason

Comment: Yes, it could be.